# Use mezzanine together with angularjs

Tags: django, angularjs, mezzanine

I'm setting up a simple website, and I wanted to integrate angularjs for the UI.  However, it seems the CMS takes over everything and serves up everything, including anything I want served up through angularjs.

My urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    (r'^users/', include('apps.site_users.urls')),
    url('^$', 'mezzanine.pages.views.page', {'slug': '/'}, name='home'),
    url('', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
    ('^', include('mezzanine.urls')),
)
```

I have all the necessary changes for angularjs to work since without the CMS, everything loads just fine, but this means I can't serve up the other pages I have in the CMS.  Any ideas on what needs to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily setup Mezzanine to work with Angular in [HTML5 Mode](http://scotch.io/quick-tips/js/angular/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag) by setting up your app's routing on Angular and your base URLs via Django, making sure that any uncaught URL scheme redirects to the "home" URL:

On Django:

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns("",
    # Change the admin prefix here to use an alternate URL for the
    # admin interface, which would be marginally more secure.
    ("^admin/", include(admin.site.urls)),

    # If you'd like more granular control over the patterns in
    # ``mezzanine.urls``, go right ahead and take the parts you want
    # from it, and use them directly below instead of using
    # ``mezzanine.urls``.
    ("^", include("mezzanine.urls")),

    # AngularJS HTML5 mode (ie, remove the /#/ from URLs):
    # We need to redirect any uncaught URL schemes to the default home view.
    # http://scotch.io/quick-tips/js/angular/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag
    url(r'^.*$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name='home'),

    # etc...
)
```

On Angular:

```
// app.js
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: '/static/app/views/home.html',
    })
    .when('/profile/:profileId', {
      templateUrl: '/static/app/views/profile.html',
      controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
    })
    .when('/results', {
      templateUrl: '/static/app/views/results.html',
      controller: 'ResultsCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });
});
```

On HTML:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="es" ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <!-- etc -->
  </head>
  <!-- etc -->
</html>
```

Related blog post [here](https://rebelliard.com/blog/integrating-angularjs-django).

Comment: Awesome!  I'd long since given up on this, but I'll give it a try

Comment: @StephenM Did it work? If so you might want to accept this as the answer.

Comment: @nueverest I'd forgotten to update that here...thanks